# How can I avoid the feed link is printed in my theme?

Tags: views, theming, 8, feeds, navigation

My current theme displays a *Subscribe to* link that is output from 
the core/themes/stable/templates/misc/feed-icon.html.twig template. I don't want to display it in my theme. Whatever I try, I can't find which template or which string prints this link.

How can I avoid the link is printed?

Comment: Do you just want to remove the display of feed icon or remove the feed altogether?

Comment: Sweet, then chrisshattuck's answer is perfect.

Comment: MrD has provided that answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is a view, you can hide the feed icon using [this method](https://www.drupal.org/node/2664802).

> Go to Structure > Views > Frontpage > Edit. Then click on "Feed" at the top. In the second drop-down box, select "Disable Feed." Then "Save" the change.

Comment: That will disable the whole feed, which may not be the desired outcome (just remove the display of the icon).

Answer (score 1):

You can use **hook_preprocess** with code:

```
function YOUR_THEME_preprocess_views_view(&$vars) {
  $vars['feed_icons'] = FALSE;
}
```

See [views-view.html.twig](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!modules!views!templates!views-view.html.twig/8.2.x) for more detail.